# MySql, count data from 3 different tables, optimized queryies

Tags: mysql

On a post page, I'm trying to display the number of comments, the number of user's subscriptions, and the number of bookmarks

I have 3 different tables like:
subscribes
comments
bookmarks

and i have 3 separate requests for that

```
SELECT count (*) FROM subscribes where userId = 5
SELECT count (*) FROM comments
SELECT count (*) FROM bookmarks where userId = 5
```

How can this be optimized?

Comment: Although its not clear what you mean by "Optimized". but as advice, you dont want to call the database with these queries every time someone opens the post-page. as an alternative you can cache these values (for a short time interval)  and rely on the cache to retrieve these numbers. if you can clarify what is it that you want to optimize we might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

- `subscribes` and `bookmarks` need `INDEX(userId)`.
- Doesn't `comments` nees a `WHERE`, too?
- You could combine the three statements into one roundtrip to the server, but this would only save a millisecond or so.
- If the counts are huge, then consider building and maintaining Summary tables.
- Notice how search engines no longer say "1,234,567 hits", but instead say "over 1 million hits" or say nothing?  Rethink your need for the statistics.
- Provide the stats only if a user asks for them (JS + AJAX).